# Do i need multiple docker containers OR create single container and install other softwares in it?

Tags: docker

i have a java application that needs both Tomcat 7 server & MySQL DB to run. Now i have 1 Docker container with Tomcat 7 in it, now should i create one more container for  MySQL DB OR shall i install MYSQL in Tomcat 7 container itself ? How does the big companies do ideally ?

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice, you should only launch one process per container. Although it is possible to [Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) it is not recommended.

For MYSQL, there are already docker images for it on [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). You just need to start one image and connect your application container to it.

Answer (score 0):

## How to setup your system

The best way would be with multiple containers.

As [yamenk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49383404/8041461) says, the best way would be to run one image of [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and one image of [tomcat](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/).

## How to make the 2 containers run together

Using docker-compose you can define a system made of containers, and allow them to talk to each other. This has the advantage that it is easier to scale 2 smaller containers, than one massive container, and you can spin up the whole system in one go, with dependencies automatically managed

## Why not run everything in 1 massive container

There are many good reasons, some of which are listed in [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/451/4114) answer